# Update Previous Value and replace null to previous value

Tags: mysql

Please find the below scenario to sum previous value and replace zero to previous value.

```
Create table joborder (
   jo_no       int(10),
   jo_date     datetime,
   jo_status   char(10)
);

insert into joborder values( 1,'01-03-13','A');    
insert into joborder values( 2,'01-03-13','A');    
Insert into joborder values (3,'01-03-13','A');    
insert into joborder values( 4,'04-03-13','A');    
insert into joborder values(5,'08-03-13','B');    
insert into joborder values( 6,'12-03-13','C');
```

Status:

`A` means Completed

`B` means Progress

`C` means Dev

I want a report as below

```
Date         TotalJoborder    A      B     C
---------------------------------------------    
01-03-13      3               3      0     0    
04-03-13      1               0      1     0    
08-03-13      1               0      1     0    
12-03-13      1               0      0     1
```

I want a report as below should increment previous values and display previous value as well.

```
Date         TotalJoborder    A      B     C
---------------------------------------------    
01-03-13      3               3      0     0    
04-03-13      4               3      1     0    
08-03-13      5               3      1     1    
12-03-13      6               4      1     1
```

Comment: what you want exactly, first one second one

Answer (score 0):

For the first output you can do something like this:

```
select jo_date, 
       count(*) as total_job_order,
       sum(case when jo_status= 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as status_a,
       sum(case when jo_status= 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as status_b,
       sum(case when jo_status= 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as status_c
from joborder
group by jo_date
order by jo_date;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ab191/1

For the "running total" you can do something like this:

```
select jo_date,
       (select count(*) from joborder j2 where j2.jo_date <= t1.jo_date) as running_sum,
       status_b,
       status_c
from (
  select jo_date, 
         sum(case when jo_status= 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as status_a,
         sum(case when jo_status= 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as status_b,
         sum(case when jo_status= 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as status_c
  from joborder
  group by jo_date
  order by jo_date
) t1
```

Btw: I'm almost 100% certain that you don't want `char(10)` for the `jo_status` column, but `varchar(10)` instead.

Comment: super thx very much i got the solution by using <= condition thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

select jo_date,
       (select count(*) from joborder j2 where j2.jo_date <= t1.jo_date) as running_sum,
       status_b,
       status_c
from (
  select jo_date, 
         sum(case when jo_status= 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as status_a,
         sum(case when jo_status= 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as status_b,
         sum(case when jo_status= 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as status_c
  from joborder
  group by jo_date
  order by jo_date
) t1